# Connection issues

Tags: wi-fi

My Wi-Fi connection was very inconsistent, in times it would just be on 'Saved', and sometimes it's connected. I thought that I could maybe fix the issue by changing the last number of my IP address. As I read somewhere that the number must be from 1 to 225, I put a few numbers, but for every single one I would get 'Connected, no internet'. Is this an issue, because I have three members of my family that use the Wi-Fi. One has the same problem as me, and one has excellent connection. The one with the excellent connection connected to the Wi-Fi the first in our family, so does that have anything to do with his excellent connection and our poor connection? Thank you in advance.

Comment: usually DHCP Server gives you IP address and this has nothing to do with WiFi, it is not related at all. there are some incompatible combinations with speed rate protocols 802.11b/g/n/ac and encryption methods WPA/WPA2 TKIP/AES which aren't supported on all phone models. set the router to 802.11n-only + WPA2-CCMP (AES) and delete all previous saved networks before re-connecting phone

Comment: My phone is Umidigi A5 Pro, of the other family member with inconsistent connection Wiko View 2.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no common solution for this. try a few combinations and report back if this makes any difference. weak signal can have several causes